# Vb.net How to remove duplicates from an Array?

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim ItemList As New ArrayList()

For i = 0 To dgExtract.Items.Count - 1
        gRow = dgExtract.Items(i)
        chk = gRow.FindControl("chkSelect")
        If chk.Checked Then
            sEmail = gRow.Cells(7).Text
            dim number as string = Regex.Replace(sEmail,"[^0-9]","")
            if number.length = 11 then
                ItemList.Add(number)
            end if
        end if              
Next
```

I build up the ItemList array with the above code. How do i remove any duplicates in this array?

Comment: I wouldn't use an ArrayList ever (well, maybe there would be some strange situation where I would). Better to use a List(Of String) in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately, sometimes we are stuck supporting legacy code, i.e. .Net 1.1.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting:

```
Dim number As Integer
Dim num As String
Dim al As New ArrayList()
If Not (al.Contains(number)) Then
    al.Add(number)
End If
```

Getting:

```
For Each number In al
    num = number.ToString()
Next
```

Answer (score 5):

Rather than checking and removing the duplicate elements you can check whether it is in the array, if it doesn't exist you can add to array, else do nothing.

Declare a `List<string>` object named for instance `list`. In the loop:

```
If Not list.Contains(number) Then
    list.Add(number)
```

Answer (score 4):

You'd declare some array (or List, or whatever collection you may prefer) and would do something like:

```
Array.Resize(numberArray, numberArray.Length + 1)
numberArray[numberArray.Length - 1] = number
```

Then you could use LINQ:

```
numberArray.Distinct()
```

And then, iterate the array and do whatever you need.

EDIT: Better what Srinivasan__ said, check whether the item exists, and if it doesn't add it. To check for it, you can use Exists(). Or if using something like a List, Contains().

Comment: Why is this not #1?

Comment: `Distinct is not a member of System.array`

Answer (score 1):

```
        int i;
        int j;
        int count = 0;
        int[] list = new int[5];
        //to add 5 data with duplicate
        list[0] = 1;
        list[1] = 5;
        list[2] = 2;
        list[3] = 4;
        list[4] = 5;
        #region toremovetheduplicate
        int c = 0, flag = 0;
        int[] list1 = new int[5];
        for (i = 0; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            flag = 0;
            for (j = i + 1; j < list.Length; j++)
            {

                if (i != j)
                {
                    if (list[i] == list[j])
                    {
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (flag == 0)
            {
                list1[c] = list[i];
                c++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check like this

```
if number.length = 11 then
    if Not ItemList.contains(number)
        ItemList.Add(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this, I tried the following code ; it works fine, I'm using a CheckedListBox to view results.
There 2 arraylist used. 'Darray' holding the original list of duplicated strings. Then, 'FinArray' to dump the non-duplicated strings, then display the 'FinArray' contents in the listbox:

```
    Sub CleanDupes()
    ' Clear listbox
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Clear()
    ' Create Final Array for non-duped data
    Dim FinArray As New ArrayList
    Dim InitFinarray, DarrayN, FinArrayN As String
    ' Add first record from original array into new array
    FinArray.Add(Darray.Item(0))
    InitFinarray = FinArray.Item(0)
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add("Select/Unselect All")
    CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(InitFinarray)
    ' Loop into Orig Array and compare each record with strings in new array,
    ' if exist in new array, then skip, else add it
    For n As Integer = 0 To Darray.Count - 1
        DarrayN = Darray.Item(n)
        For n2 As Integer = 0 To FinArray.Count - 1
            If FinArray.Contains(DarrayN) Then
            Else
                FinArray.Add(DarrayN)
                FinArray.Sort(1, FinArray.Count - 1, Nothing)
            End If
        Next
    Next
    'Display New Non-Duped Array in listbox
    For n3 As Integer = 1 To FinArray.Count - 1
        CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(FinArray(n3))
    Next
     End Sub
```