# print only distinct or duplicate elements of array and ignore the rest of elements - vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net, distinct

is there a function on vb to print only the distinct elements of array, not List or ArrayList? My code is this
`Dim TestVal(4) as String`
`TestVal(0) = "a"`
`TestVal(1) = "a"`
`TestVal(2) = "b"`
`TestVal(3) = "c"`
`TestVal(4) = "c"`
`Label7.Text = String.Join(",", TestVal.Distinct())`
what i want to be my output would be is  `a,c` and would **just ignore the other elements**. Is there such a function like `Distinct()` or `Where` clause?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185149/vb-net-how-to-remove-duplicates-from-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vb.net How to remove duplicates from an Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185149/vb-net-how-to-remove-duplicates-from-an-array)

Comment: How comfortable are you with lambdas and LINQ?

Comment: @tgolisch I'm guessing they've never heard of them, else they wouldn't be asking!!

Comment: hello @tgolisch, i'm new to vb and i'm struggling to find ways.

Comment: Lambdas and LINQ are powerful, but difficult (not nice for beginners).  Miguel and Lorenzo's suggestion (using a loop) would work well.  So would a `Collection`.

Comment: How many elements will you need? I only ask because the simplest answer won't perform well for large sets of data (more than 1000).

Comment: I've seen how LINQ manipulate strings, like `Distinct()`, i'll try to dig.

Comment: 20 - 40 strings only

Comment: Do you want to print "a,c" or "a,b,c"?

Comment: `TestVal.GroupBy(Function(s) s).Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).SelectMany(Function(s) s).Distinct()`

Comment: duplicate elements only once, `a,c`

Comment: @Jimi , you're code printed all of elements, i tried to modify it though  `TestVal.GroupBy(Function(s) s).Where(Function(g) g.Count() > 1).SelectMany  (Function(s) s)  
        Label7.Text = String.Join(",", TestVal.Distinct())`  it only prints `a,b,c` . i tried to change the `Count` too but still.

Comment: That snippet I posted is meant to substitute the `TestVal.Distinct()` you currently have in your code, inside `String.Join()` You could also assign it to a local variable before passing it to the Join() method, to simplify the *handling*.

Comment: hello @Mary, you mean this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find duplicates only, you can use LINQ grouping as follows:

```
Dim q = From p In TestVal
        Group By p Into Group, Count()
        Where Count > 1
        Select p
        Order By p

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", q)) ' will print "a,c"
```

Note that `Where Count > 1` is to select only values of more than one (dupicates).

In other hand, if you wish to find only unique values, change the `Where Count > 1` to `Where Count = 1` as follows:

```
Dim q = From p In TestVal
        Group By p Into Group, Count()
        Where Count = 1
        Select p
        Order By p

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", q)) ' will print "b"
```

Either way, the `Order By p` is optional. You may leave it out it if you dont need the result string join to be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try with this code:

```
Private Function GetDuplicatitions(array As String()) As String
    Dim result = ""
    For Each item In array
        If IsInList(result, item) Then Continue For
        If HasDuplications(array, item) Then result &= item & ","
    Next
    Return result
End Function

Private Function HasDuplications(array As String(), text As String) As Boolean
    Dim count = 0
    For Each item In array
        If item = text Then count = count + 1
        If count > 1 Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function

Private Function IsInList(list As String, item As String) As Boolean
    For Each duplicated In list.Split(",")
        If item = duplicated Then Return True
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

Maybe you want to put it in a helper class. To use it you just call it like:

```
Dim list = {"a", "a", "b", "c", "c"}
Label7.Text = GetDuplicatitions(list)
```

Comment: it printed `a,a,c,c` i tried to `Label7.Text = GetDuplicatitions(TestVal.Distinct())` and it crashed (lol),